# The best way to use Video with QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, opengl, video, qgraphicsview, phonon

I am currently using Phonon VideoWidgets inside of a QGraphicsScene using a QGraphicsProxyWidget.

I have my viewport set to a QGLWidget.

However, it causes me big issues when I try to apply some transforms to the video such as a rotation that isn't evenly divisible by 90 degrees since then it slows my program down a lot.

After reading the few things I managed to find on the subject I found that it seems that when using a VideoWidget inside a QGraphicsProxyWidget it will do software transforms which would explain the massive slowdown.

So I was wondering if there is a better way to render the video.

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible render your video to an opengl framebuffer or pixelbuffer, and have your window draw/transform the texture.